# Python -- ConnectionError: Max retries exceeded

Tags: python, node.js, http, webserver

I occasionally get this error when my server (call it Server A) makes requests to a resource on another one of my servers (all it Server B):

`ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='some_ip', port=some_port): Max retries exceeded with url: /some_url/ (Caused by : [Errno 111] Connection refused)`

The message in the exception is
`message : None: Max retries exceeded with url: /some_url/ (Caused by redirect)`
which I include because it has that extra piece of information `(caused by redirect)`.

As I said, I control both servers involved in this request, so I can make changes to either and/or both.  Also, the error appears to be intermittent, in that it doesn't happen every time.

Potentially relevant information -- Server A is a Python server running apache, and Server B is a NodeJS server.  I am not exactly a web server wizard, so beyond that, I'm not exactly sure what information would be relevant.

Does anyone know exactly what this error means, or how to go about investigating a fix?  Or, does anyone know which server is likely to be the problem, the one making the request, or the one receiving it?

**Edit:** The error has begun happening with our calls to external web resources also.

Comment: Can you give more details about server A, like what libraries you are importing.

Comment: I'm using Python Requests library to make the request

Comment: Hard to tell, but seems like you have the front-line Apache configured to redirect a URL to another one that is **NOT FORWARDED** to nodejs. I think the apache configuration here is the important piece of data.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn apache config for which server, A or B?

Comment: Cant't tell exactly. If you are using proxy :http://obroll.com/max-retries-exceeded-for-url-in-requests-module-python-solved/

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a  CONN Refused on "some_ip" and port. That's likely caused by 
  - No server actually listening on that port/IP combination
  - Firewall settings that send Conn Refused (less likely a cause!)
  - Third - a misconfigured (more likely) or busy server, that cannot handle requests.

I Believe When - server A is trying to connect to server B you are getting that error. (Assuming it's Linux and/or some unix derivative) what does netstat -ln -tcp show on the server? (man netstat to understand the flags - what we are doing here is - trying to find which all programs are listening on which port). If that indeed shows your server B listening - iptables -L -n to show the firewall rules. If nothing's wrong there - it's a bad configuration of listen queue most probably. (http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/023/2333/2333s2.html) or google for listen backlog.

This most likely is a bad configuration issue on your server B. (Note: a redirect loop as someone mentioned above - not handled correctly could just end up making the server busy! so possibly solving that could solve your problem as well)

Comment: Busy servers don't send ECONNREFUSED, unless the server process crashes due to a too-high load. Might be a firewall rule about too many connections/second, though. I'd turn up the verbosity on the server in question. Can't help more without a lot more digging.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gevent on your python server, you might need to upgrade the version. It looks like there's just some bug with gevent's DNS resolution.

This is a discussion from the requests library: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1202#issuecomment-13881265

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a redirect loop on the Node side.

You mention server B is the node server, you can accidentally create a redirect loop if you set up the routes incorrectly.  For example, if you are using express on server B - the Node server, you might have two routes, and assuming you keep your route logic in a separate module:

```
var routes = require(__dirname + '/routes/router')(app);
//... express setup stuff like app.use & app.configure
app.post('/apicall1', routes.apicall1);
app.post('/apicall2', routes.apicall2);
```

Then your routes/router.js might look like:

```
module.exports = Routes;

function Routes(app){
    var self = this;
    if (!(self instanceof Routes)) return new Routes(app);
    //... do stuff with app if you like
}

Routes.prototype.apicall1 = function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/apicall2');
}
Routes.prototype.apicall2 = function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/apicall1');
}
```

That example is obvious, but you might have a redirect loop hidden in a bunch of conditions in some of those routes.  I'd start with the edge cases, like what happens at the end of the conditionals within the routes in question, what is the default behavior if the call for example doesn't have the right parameters and what is the exception behavior?

As an aside, you can use something like node-validator (https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) to help determine and handle incorrect request or post parameters

```
// Inside router/routes.js:
var check = require('validator').check;

function Routes(app){ /* setup stuff */ }

Routes.prototype.apicall1 = function(req, res){
    try{
        check(req.params.csrftoken, 'Invalid CSRF').len(6,255);
        // Handle it here, invoke appropriate business logic or model, 
        // or redirect, but be careful! res.redirect('/secure/apicall2');
    }catch(e){
        //Here you could Log the error, but don't accidentally create a redirect loop
        // send appropriate response instead
        res.send(401);
    }
}
```

To help determine if it is a redirect loop you can do one of several things, you can use curl to hit the url with the same post parameters (assuming it is a post, otherwise  you can just use chrome, it'll error out in the console if it notices a redirect loop), or you can write to stdout on the Node server or syslog out inside of the offending route(s).

Hope that helps, good thing you mentioned the "caused by redirect" part, that is I think the problem.

The example situation above uses express to describe the situation, but of course the problem can exist using just connect, other frameworks, or even your own handler code as well if you aren't using any frameworks or libraries at all.  Either way, I'd make it a habit to put in good parameter checking and always test your edge cases, I've run myself into this problem exactly when I've been in a hurry in the past.

Comment: The above error is ECONNREFUSED. This is an IP problem, indicating that the server process is not running, and has nothing whatsoever to do with HTTP redirects.